# iCalendar - Update meeting body without it looking like date/time has changed

Tags: plsql, icalendar, outlook-2010

I am creating and sending the following iCalendar invite to Outlook (V14 - part of MS Office Professional Plus 2010) using PLSQL which generates the following:

```
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----_=_NextPart"
Subject: SUBJECT
Date: TUESDAY  , 30-OCT-18 11:42
From: <123@ABC.COM> 
To: 234@ABC.COM
------_=_NextPart
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

You must have an HTML enabled client to view this message.

------_=_NextPart
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset="iso-8859-1"

BODY TEXT

------_=_NextPart
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
Content-Type: text/calendar;
  method=REQUEST;
  name="meeting.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Your company name//NONSGML ICAL_EVENT//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1234@yoururl.com
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20181030T114206
ORGANIZER;CN="ORANISER_NAME":MAILTO:123@ABC.COM
DTSTART:20181106T121200
DTEND:20181106T121300
SUMMARY:
LOCATION:LOCATION
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

------_=_NextPart--
```

I then just want to update the message invite details (not the date/time, location, or attendees. Just the body text). Note that i use the same UID but increment the sequence:

```
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----_=_NextPart"
Subject: SUBJECT
Date: TUESDAY  , 30-OCT-18 11:48
From: <123@ABC.COM> 
To: 234@ABC.COM
------_=_NextPart
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

You must have an HTML enabled client to view this message.

------_=_NextPart
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset="iso-8859-1"

**BODY TEXT UPDATE**

------_=_NextPart
Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage
Content-Type: text/calendar;
  method=REQUEST;
  name="meeting.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Your company name//NONSGML ICAL_EVENT//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:1234@yoururl.com
SEQUENCE:1
DTSTAMP:20181030T114850
ORGANIZER;CN="ORANISER_NAME":MAILTO:123@ABC.COM
DTSTART:20181106T121200
DTEND:20181106T121300
SUMMARY:
LOCATION:LOCATION
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

------_=_NextPart--
```

The issue is that although the body text update comes through, the meeting date/time is highlighted in orange and looks like it has been changed:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated !
Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Using the same UID is essential.  Don't update the Sequence number for minor updates - this is for significant revisions that might affect the participation of attendees.  From the spec https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/sequence.html:

> It is monotonically incremented by the "Organizer's" CUA each time the
>   "Organizer" makes a **significant revision** to the calendar component.
>   When the "Organizer" makes changes to one of the following properties,
>   the sequence number MUST be incremented:
>
> . "DTSTART"
>
> . "DTEND"
>
> . "DUE"
>
> . "RDATE"
>
> . "RRULE"
>
> . "EXDATE"
>
> . "EXRULE"
>
> . "STATUS"
>
> In addition, changes made by the "Organizer" to other properties can
>   also force the sequence number to be incremented. The "Organizer" CUA
>   MUST increment the sequence number when ever it makes changes to
>   properties in the calendar component that the "Organizer" deems will
>   **jeopardize the validity of the participation status** of the
>   "Attendees". For example, changing the location of a meeting from one
>   locale to another distant locale could effectively impact the
>   participation status of the "Attendees".

Comment: Sorry for the delay .. got sidetracked by another project. I tried this (didn't update sequence number but used same UID) and it didn't work unfortunately. Any other ideas ? Thanks in advance

Comment: No sorry - might be an outlook 'bug'.  Did you try with totally clean data? IE new event then with new non-essential update ?

Comment: yeh i tried new event, uid etc and only changed body test and didn’t increment seq